# Integrating react native code into existing android project

Tags: android, react-native, integration

Integrating react native code into the existing android project facing the following error.

***Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void androidx.core.net.ConnectivityManagerCompat.()***

We are trying to add the react native project into an existing android app. With the following reference link:

> https://medium.com/mindorks/react-native-integration-with-existing-app-f2757c2e672d

. While switching from Android Main activity to Reactnative activity,
we get the following exception

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void androidx.core.net.ConnectivityManagerCompat.()' is inaccessible to class 'com.facebook.react.modules.netinfo.NetInfoModule' (declaration of 'com.facebook.react.modules.netinfo.NetInfoModule`

. Please suggest.

Comment: did you found the solution?

Comment: `IllegalAccessError` mostly happens when importing the wrong version of libraries, because they try to call a specific method from the class but it doesn't exist anymore(or yet) at the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The guide you linked to is 3 years old, there has been a lot of changes in RN (and in Android, Gradle, etc.) during that time.

Can you try this guide: https://blog.usejournal.com/integrating-react-native-with-existing-android-apps-efficiently-3b39f2e061bd ? I used it a few weeks ago and it worked for me.